# On page refresh navigate to another route vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have two pages `home` and `about`. so while refreshing `home` page i need to naviagate to `about` page. so in `home.vue` i written like this.

```
created () {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.reloadHandler)
}

destroyed () {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.reloadHandler)
}
```

and in the `reloadHandler` method i written router push to `about` page.

```
reloadHandler () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$router.push('/about')
  })
}
```

Is it possible to do this with vue-router. Or is there any way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Due to browser security and privacy concerns, it is not possible entirely in Vue.js/client-side. It will never be foolproof.

The best solution is to use a server-side redirect to handle this situation. When a page is refreshed, the server will receive the request. When the server gets the request from `/home` route, then it should redirect to `/about` using HTTP status `302` and `Location` header.

Comment: So is there a way to trigger a event and then redirect to another url. Like when we click the button the redirect url works right. Thanks

Comment: @htoniv, yes. it is possible. simply listen for buttons `@click` handler and redirect using something like `window.location.href = '/about'`. This should refresh the page.

Comment: Not direct click handler. On the page refresh i need to trigger the click handler and then redirect like this. https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/8adLqt5u/

Comment: @htoniv, as I said, there are ways but not really foolproof.

Comment: Okay sure @Harshal better i use server-side redirect to handle this situation thanks.

Comment: this command will refresh the page `this.$router.go()`